# angular6 lazy module asking for path in ProvideRoutes

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading, multisite

I've made a test for a multisite app which loads a module depending of the hostname detected.

The test: *https://module-lazy-load-for-multi-site.stackblitz.io*

It's working fine, except that in some tutorials I saw, they are not putting a path property in the provideRoutes route.

What I see in tutorials:

```
{ loadChildren: './lazy2/lazy2.module#Lazy2Module'}
```

But me, if I don't, it throws an error, forcing me to put a path property:

```
{
  path: 'can be anything here',
  loadChildren: './lazy2/lazy2.module#Lazy2Module'
}
```

I could just let it like this, but I'm asking myself why they don't have to put the path in the tutorials I'm finding, and me yes.
Am I missing something? Is it because I'm using Angular6 and them a previous version?

Thanks

Comment: Which tutorials are you talking about?
In angular docs, they put always a path (https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: Thanks for answering.
This one for example: https://github.com/rahulsahay19/Dynamic-Import-Angular/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts I had another one but I can't find it. They are probably just wrong. But I find strange to have to add an unused path when the module will be loaded dynamically and not on a specific route.

Comment: I think they are wrong yes.
You can just say: `path:''` if you don't want a unused path.

Comment: `path` is a required property. The tutorial might be out of date or simply wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!